# How retreive saved data from gravity forms in my template?

Tags: plugins, database, plugin-gravity-forms

I want to display the completed gravity form values in frontpage using entry id and form id.
I know about this but unable to retrieve values

`GFFormsModel::get_leads($form_id)` 
    returns a list of entries for a form (maybe you know that one already), where each item in the array is itself an array, an "Entry object"
`GFFormsModel::get_form_meta($form_id)` returns a list of field meta elements (i.e. describes name, type, rules etc.) in the form, where each item in the array is a "Field object"

Once you have an Entry object, you can access the fields as elements, by field number. If you need to find a field by name or type, you need to iterate over the list of fields in the form to get a match, and then access the entry's field by field ID.

NB: determining a field's type is best done by passing the field's meta element to `GFFormsModel::get_input_type($field)`

Edit: note also that only the first 200 characters of each field are returned in the Entry object. If you have fields that store more information, you'll need to ask for it, e.g. by calling `GFFormsModel::get_field_value_long($lead, $field_number, $form)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be to use actual merge tags in your content. This can be done with the Gravity Forms Post Content Merge Tags plugin and also supports a global merge tags feature so you can fetch the entry data by the field label (without the field ID).

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-post-content-merge-tags/#global-merge-tags